# mongodb $in query slow performance

Tags: mongodb, performance, optimization

I have a database that contains a collection around 40MB with the following structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5eabcc5a31e128ea59623b63"),
    "i" : "8759548",
    "f" : "31",
    "is" : "0",
    "a" : "0",
    "v" : 0
}
```

From my application a want group by value. The collection contains **600K documents** and typically i want to ask a group for **400K** or something. So my query has an **$in clause with 400K** of string values.

When i run a stress test i saw that the **perfomance was very slow**

My query is:

```
[
 {"$match":{"i":{"$in":["8759652","8759664",.......]}, "is":{"$in":["0"]}}}},
 {"$group":{"_id":"$v","number":{"$sum":1}}}
]
```

and i have already the index i_is: 1

My question is if there anyone can propose a storage solution or query optimization - maybe not passing 400K values in clause to optimize the query

Comment: Sounds like you need to redesign how you store the data to find some common fields you can query on.

Comment: Have you checked the query plan? I suspect that your index is not being used because your are using `$in` operator in both fields or it is doing an index scan which can probably lead to slow performance

Comment: What is the source of the `400k` values (used with the `$in`)? What is the functionality  / purpose of this query in your application?